# Excel/VBA Breakdown field

Tags: vba, excel

Bit of a complicated task I have to do but I will try and explain. I have an excel file with 23000 lines of data which I am importing into a website. Each one has a field like so:

```
Category | other data | other data 2 

Foods/Dog/Treats Pre-Pack | 1223 | image.jpg
```

I need it to grab each line and add a new line below it for each "/" so turning the above into:

```
Category | other data | other data 2 

[blank in original line] | 1223 | image.jpg

Foods | [blank field] | [blank field]

Foods/Dog | [blank field] | [blank field]

Foods/Dog/Treats Pre-Pack | [blank field] | [blank field]
```

So the script needs to add a new line for each category but keeping the original category in front of it. So turning `category/category2/category 3` into 4 lines of: `[blank] - category - category/category2 - category/category2/category 3`

Does anyone know a way or script to do this?

Thanks, Simon

Note: The worksheet is called "test" and the category column starts at E2 and goes to E23521

I have the following script:

```
Sub test()
    Dim a, i As Long, ii As Long, e, n As Long
    Dim b(), txt As String, x As Long
    With Range("a1").CurrentRegion
        a = .Value
        txt = Join$(Application.Transpose(.Columns(5).Value))
        With CreateObject("VBScript.RegExp")
            .Global = True
            .Pattern = "/"
            x = .Execute(txt).Count * 2
        End With
        ReDim b(1 To UBound(a, 1) + x, 1 To UBound(a, 2))
        For i = 1 To UBound(a, 1)
            If a(i, 5) <> "" Then
                For Each e In Split(a(i, 5), "/")
                    n = n + 1
                    For ii = 1 To UBound(a, 2)
                        b(n, ii) = a(i, ii)
                    Next
                    b(n, 5) = Trim$(e)
                Next
            End If
        Next
        .Resize(n).Value = b
    End With
End Sub
```

This seems to create a new row as I need it to but does not keep the slash structuring moving up with each one. And also dosnt add a blank line on all the new ones and make the original category value blank.

SOLVED:

```
Sub splitEmUp()
    Dim splitter() As String 'this is storage space for the split function
    Dim i As Integer ' main-loop for counter "which cell we are on"
    Dim j As Integer ' splitter for-loop counter "which section of the split are we on"
    Range("E2").Activate 'starting in cell e2 because row 1 is headers and category is located in the B column

   For i = 0 To 24000 'from beginning to end i=0 means e2, i=1 means e3
        ActiveCell.Offset(i, 0).Value = Replace(ActiveCell.Offset(i, 0).Value, " / ", "!@#")
        splitter = Split(ActiveCell.Offset(i, 0), "/") 'split the cell based on / and store it in splitter
        If (UBound(splitter)) > 0 Then 'if a split occurred
            ActiveCell.Offset(i, 0).Value = "" 'set the activecell to blank
            Debug.Print i
            ActiveCell.Offset(i + 1, 0).EntireRow.Insert shift:=xlDown, copyorigin:=xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove 'insert a new row and shift everything down

            ActiveCell.Offset(i + 1, 0).Value = splitter(0) 'initialize the "Down" cells
            ActiveCell.Offset(i + 1, 0).Value = Replace(ActiveCell.Offset(i + 1, 0).Value, "!@#", " / ")
            For j = 1 To UBound(splitter)
                ActiveCell.Offset(i + j + 1).EntireRow.Insert shift:=xlDown, copyorigin:=xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove 'create another row if it needs to
                ActiveCell.Offset(i + (j + 1), 0).Value = ActiveCell.Offset(i + j).Value & "/" & splitter(j) 'fill out the new row
                ActiveCell.Offset(i + (j + 1), 0).Value = Replace(ActiveCell.Offset(i + (j + 1), 0).Value, "!@#", " / ")
            Next
            i = i + UBound(splitter) + 1 'need to step I past the new cells
            ReDim splitter(0)
            Erase splitter 'erase and eliminate splitter to avoid carry over.

        End If
    Next

End Sub
```

Comment: Is this a one-time thing or do you need code to do this automatically?  If it's a one-time task, I'd suggest playing around with Excel's built in functions.

Comment: Thankyou for the reply, this is a one time thing to be run once. I am terrible at excel and have no idea what I am doing but do know you can make macros. Any advice is needed really I have 2 days to get this done and on the verge of going insane :)

Comment: Well done :) the format of the site is generally to make an answer and mark it as the `Accepted` solution instead of writing `Solved` in the question which is more typical of traditional forums.

Comment: Simon - See what Brad said, when you're able to post a self answer then please do so. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This is what I came up with. Be sure to change the sheet names to fit your workbook. Also be sure to change the input range to fit your own input range of cells.

```
Function SplitAndWrite(inputCell As Range, TopOfOutputRange As Range, sep As String) As Range

Dim texts() As String, i As Integer, outputText As String
texts = Split(inputCell.Value, sep)
outputText = ""
TopOfOutputRange = ""   'your blank line
For i = LBound(texts) To UBound(texts)
    outputText = outputText & sep & texts(i)
    TopOfOutputRange.Offset(i + 1) = outputText
Next i

Set SplitAndWrite = TopOfOutputRange.Offset(UBound(texts) + 1)

End Function

Sub THEPOPULATOR()

    Dim s3 As Worksheet, s4 As Worksheet
    Set s3 = Sheets("Sheet1")
    Set s4 = Sheets("Sheet2")
    Dim inputrange As Range, c As Range, outputrange As Range
    Set outputrange = s4.Range("A1")
    Set inputrange = s3.Range(s3.Cells(2, 1), s3.Cells(2, 1).End(xlDown)) 'cells(2,1) = "A1". change this to your top input cell. then the second half will find the bottom cell on its own. This is the same as pressing Ctrl+down

    For Each c In inputrange
        s3.Range(c.Offset(0, 1), c.Offset(0, c.End(xlToRight).Column)).Copy outputrange.Offset(1, 1)
        Set outputrange = SplitAndWrite(c, outputrange.Offset(1), "/")
    Next c

End Sub
```

Comment: Thankyou so much! Will give this a try now

Comment: Okay this seems to do something but not quite how I need it to. I have more than 1 column with data and I need it to add a new lines under each line of data without editting the other columns. Also leaving in the main structure. so not seperating each /

Comment: Thankyou for the reply again Brad. Its looking much better :) thankyou. Still a few issues however. It dosnt leave the dash in so makes it: FoodsDogDry Puppy  Junior instead of Foods/Dog/Dry Puppy  Junior. Also all the new lines copy data down from original line however all rows should be blank on the new lines. And last of all :) the original category should be blank carrying down all data onto new lines under it. Thankyou again

Comment: I think I'm confused about `Category | other data |` are these column headers? I don't understand what you mean by `all rows should be blank on the new lines`. I did fix the "/" being left off though.

Comment: Yes these are headers, I mean the new lines that are being created should have blank data. So the line which has "Foods" in category should have all of fields blank. so:
[blank in original line] | 1223 | image.jpg <new line>
Foods | [blank field] | [blank field]

Comment: ok, so the only thin that dictates new line creation is the first column? All other columns in the source dataset are copied without alteration onto the first line?

Comment: Yes thats correct, so all data on original line stays as it is, but all data in first column is shifted onto the new lines. leaving the original field blank. Thankyou again :)

Comment: Ok, one last try and if that's not right we can move to Chat.

Comment: Okay, it added dashes but it looses it after the first one, here is an image of what it is doing: http://i49.tinypic.com/2vmvcie.jpg and here is an image of the original file: http://i49.tinypic.com/ok9x03.jpg also to make things even more confusing! just noticed one of the categorys is "Dry Puppy / Junior" with spaces to show that is the name of the category and not 2 categorys. Not sure if we can have it miss the / if it has a space at either side. Chat sounds good not to sure how to do that though.

Comment: go here and we can continue http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/18748/excel-vba-breakdown-field

Comment: It says I must have 20 reputation to talk there, do you have skype at all? Again thankyou so much for all the help, really saving my backside

Comment: That update seems to have worked, it is adding individual categorys. However it is not adding the blank columns and shifting down all the other data.

Comment: That data is for other information on the product, this is what it should look like: http://i50.tinypic.com/4rc5m1.jpg

Comment: weak. I'll come back to this later tonight then.

Comment: Okay, thankyou for the help anyway hopefully you can solve this one later

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example from another solution [How to split cell in a row with Excel](https://superuser.com/q/486294/160170), which I modified just a tiny bit to fit your situation:

```
Public Sub solutionJook()
  Dim arr() As Variant
  Dim arrSum() As Variant
  Dim arrResult() As Variant
  Dim arrTemp As Variant

  Dim i As Long
  Dim j As Long
  Dim h As Long
  Dim lngSplitColumn As Long
  'input of array to seperate -> should cover all columns+rows of your data
  arr = Range("A1:C2")
  'specify which column has the values to be split up -> here this is the category column
  lngSplitColumn = 2

  'using the boundries of the given range,
  'arrSum has now always the right boundries for the first dimension
  ReDim Preserve arrSum(LBound(arr, 2) To UBound(arr, 2), 1 To 1)

  'create the array with seperated A B C
  For i = LBound(arr, 1) To UBound(arr, 1)
    'use split to make Foods/Dog/Treats Pre-Pack into an array, using '\' (chr(92)) as indicator
    arrTemp = Split(arr(i, lngSplitColumn), Chr(92))
    'every value of arrTemp creates a new row
    For j = LBound(arrTemp) To UBound(arrTemp)
      'loop through all input columns and create the new row
      For h = LBound(arr, 2) To UBound(arr, 2)
        If h = lngSplitColumn Then
          'setup the value of the splitted column
          Dim k as long
          arrSum(h, UBound(arrSum, 2)) = arrTemp(LBound(arrTemp))
          for k = LBound(arrTemp)+1 to j
            arrSum(h, UBound(arrSum, 2)) = arrSum(h, UBound(arrSum, 2)) & "\" & arrTemp(k)  'set Foods Foods/Dog Foods/Dog/Treats Pre-Pack
          next k
        Else
          'setup the value of any other column
          arrSum(h, UBound(arrSum, 2)) = arr(i, h) 'set Value of Column h
        End If
      Next h

      ReDim Preserve arrSum(LBound(arr, 1) To UBound(arr, 2), _
                            LBound(arrSum, 2) To (UBound(arrSum, 2) + 1))
    Next j
  Next i

  'clean up last empty row (not realy necessary)
  ReDim Preserve arrSum(LBound(arr, 1) To UBound(arr, 2), _
                        LBound(arrSum, 2) To (UBound(arrSum, 2) - 1))

  'setup transposed result array
  ReDim arrResult(LBound(arrSum, 2) To UBound(arrSum, 2), _
                  LBound(arrSum, 1) To UBound(arrSum, 1))

  'transpose the array
  For i = LBound(arrResult, 1) To UBound(arrResult, 1)
    For j = LBound(arrResult, 2) To UBound(arrResult, 2)
      arrResult(i, j) = arrSum(j, i)
    Next j
  Next i

  'specify target range
  Range(Cells(1, 5), Cells(UBound(arrResult, 1), 4 + UBound(arrResult, 2))) = arrResult

End Sub
```

You might need to adapt the target range however.

`Cells(1,5)` -> E1 is the starting point of pasting

Comment: Thankyou very much! will give this a try also

Comment: Returns this when run: run-time error 9 subscript out of range

Comment: Lines I editted are:
  'input of array to seperate -> should cover all columns+rows of your data
  arr = Range("E1:E23751")

 Range(Cells(2, 5), Cells(UBound(arrResult, 1), 4 + UBound(arrResult, 2))) = arrResult

Comment: sorry, I did this in a hurry - on the initial problem this was written for, it worked very well and fast, however, it was not fully dynamic adjustable. I will get you an update.