# Excel / Magento . CSV

Tags: excel, magento, vba

I have a big problem. I'm very stressed with getting a Magento site up and the way it handles imports via csv is mind bending!

I have basically no VBA training but I think it could help me to get this done.
Problem is with multi field csv.
I have a column header named **size**. Underneath I need 7 columns with fixed values: 38, 39, 40, ..., 44
My current csv uses single rows.
So I need multiple rows, just the cells from the size column completed with those said values.
ex:

```
HEADER1  HEADER2 HEADER3 SIZE         HEADER 4
Value    Value   Value   38,39, etc   Value
Value2   Value2  Value2  38,39, etc   Value2

I Need This:

HEADER1  HEADER2 HEADER3 SIZE         HEADER 4
Value    Value   Value   38           Value
                         39
                         40
                         41
Value2   Value2  Value2  38           Value2
                         39
                         40
                         41
```

I found a script

```
Sub InsertARow()
 'make new row
ActiveCell.EntireRow.Insert Shift:=xlDown
 'copy the row above
ActiveCell.Offset(-1, 0).EntireRow.Copy Cells(ActiveCell.Row, 1)
On Error Resume Next
 'clear every cell in the new line that does not have a formula
ActiveCell.EntireRow.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants, 23).ClearContents
End Sub
```

This inserts X rows above current selection. Is there any way to do this for all cells in selection? Autocomplete would handle the rest.
I was thinking something like

```
for i:=1 to n do 
    j:=i+7(the number of sizes i need to display) -> insert the above code for that cell.
```

and the actual completion is handled by Excel.

Comment: This seems like a product import which should only be a once off exercise so why not just manually manipulate the spreadsheet?

Answer (score 0):

You have basically the same problem as in the following questions, so you might want to apply my solution to your situation - it should not be very hard to do so.

[How to split cell in a row with Excel](https://superuser.com/q/486294/160170)

[Excel/VBA Breakdown field](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13126533/1370465)